# Error while trying to login Alfresco Community... already tried the answers given here

Tags: authentication, alfresco

The below error turns up when I try login in Alfresco 4.2

> "Your authentication details have not been recognized or Alfresco may
>   not be available at this time."
>
> http://127.0.0.1:8082/alfresco does not work..
>
> HTTP Status 404 - /alfresco
>
> type Status report
>
> message /alfresco
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

I already tried the solutions given here.. but they do not work..

Alfresco Log

```
    15:58:35,032 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
15:58:35,051 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default] complete
15:58:44,732 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Stopping 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
15:58:44,757 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Stopped 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
15:58:44,764 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vtiUrlHelper' defined in file [C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\module\org.alfresco.module.vti\context\vti-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to construct valid Sharepoint URL.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to construct valid Sharepoint URL.
    at org.alfresco.module.vti.handler.alfresco.DefaultUrlHelper.getExternalURL(DefaultUrlHelper.java:79)
    at org.alfresco.module.vti.handler.alfresco.DefaultUrlHelper.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultUrlHelper.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname at index 12: http://vIPER_PC:7070/alfresco
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHostname(URI.java:3368)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseServer(URI.java:3217)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3136)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3078)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3034)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:680)
    at org.alfresco.module.vti.handler.alfresco.DefaultUrlHelper.getExternalURL(DefaultUrlHelper.java:75)
    ... 30 more
15:58:35,032 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
15:58:35,051 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default] complete
15:58:44,732 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Stopping 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
15:58:44,757 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Stopped 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
15:58:44,764 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vtiUrlHelper' defined in file [C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\module\org.alfresco.module.vti\context\vti-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to construct valid Sharepoint URL.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to construct valid Sharepoint URL.
    at org.alfresco.module.vti.handler.alfresco.DefaultUrlHelper.getExternalURL(DefaultUrlHelper.java:79)
    at org.alfresco.module.vti.handler.alfresco.DefaultUrlHelper.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultUrlHelper.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname at index 12: http://vIPER_PC:7070/alfresco
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHostname(URI.java:3368)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseServer(URI.java:3217)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3136)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3078)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3034)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:680)
    at org.alfresco.module.vti.handler.alfresco.DefaultUrlHelper.getExternalURL(DefaultUrlHelper.java:75)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: What have you got set in your `alfresco-global.properties` file around hostnames?

Comment: [Underscores are not allowed in hostnames](http://domainkeys.sourceforge.net/underscore.html). Try using 127.0.0.1 instead of vIPER_PC in your configuration (assuming you're running everything locally)

Answer (score 2):

Your hostname is illegal since it contains a "_" character, as stated by this section of the stacktrace:

> Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname
>   at index 12: http://vIPER_PC:7070/alfresco
>       at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)

If that is in your alfresco-global.properties you should change it to a valid hostname.

Since the error is related to vti module, you could follow [this solution](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/installation-upgrades/cant-open-alfresco) that suggests to add these two lines in your `alfresco-global.properties`:

```
vti.server.external.host=127.0.0.1 
vti.server.external.port=8080
```

You can also disable the Sharepoint protocol (a.k.a. vti) if you don't really need it.